# Close parent window but child window won't be closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to develop a windows form application. In parent window a button will be used to create and show a child window form. When I close the parent window the child window also closed automatically. But I don't want to close the child window when I close the parent window. So, I want the parent window will be closed but child window will remain activated.

In parent window:

```
private void button1_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  childwindow c=new childwindow();
  c.show();
}
```

Then when I close the parent window the child window also closed.

Comment: There's more than one explanation for this, the app automatically terminates when the startup Form is closed.  Or you use the Show(owner) overload to display the "child".  You'll have to be specific, always post a snippet.

Comment: you  can try to run your app using an empty hidden form as start point and use it to create child windows. (hidden)  - parent -> (main) and (hidden) parent -> (other that is opened from main). of this way swap from main to other will not close the app.

Answer (score 1):

Hookup a method to the FormClosing event of your main form. (The one you want to close but not cause the application to exit)

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

This will cancel the closing event, and then hide the main form. 
You're going to need to handle the closing down of the application yourself now though.

Comment: maybe we need some modifications to be able to close the main form.

Comment: Actually I think @Hans suggestion is the best one. Passing a reference of the parent form to the child so the parent isn't destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have everything named, you should just be able to "hide" your window. Called like so:

```
Form.Hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the parent window outside the Application.Run(), so it can be closed and the child will stay open.

```
static void Main()
{ 
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var parentWindow = new ParentWindow();
    parentWindow.Show();
    Application.Run();  // Not application run without specific form
}
```

However you will need to have some sort of flags to terminate the application, for example if the child was not open and/or when closing the Child and when only close the child so parent won't be closed:

In the parent:

```
public static int i = 1;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var childForm = new ChildWindow();          
    childForm.Show();
}

private void Parent_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{           
    if (i==1 || i==4)
    {              
        Application.Exit();
    }

    if (i == 2)
    { 
        ChildWindow.i= 3;
    }            
}
```

In the child:

```
public static int i=2;

public ChildWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ParentWindow.i=2;

}

private void Child_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{

    if (i==3)
    {               
        Application.Exit();
    }

    ParentWindow.i = 4;

}
```